# group_by with which in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Trying to create a reference table from a dataset to find the current status of a document. Example below:

```
Document<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
change_date <- c("2015-01-01","2015-01-03","2015-01-05","2015-01-08","2015-01-05","2015-01-07","2015-01-20")
status <- c("A","A","B","C","A","B","D")
df<-data.frame(Document,change_date,status)
```

Essentially the final table should look like below:

```
  Document.x status
1          1      C
2          2      D
```

I'm currently using the code below, but surely there is a smarter way to group the Document with status where date==max(date)?

```
library(dplyr)
df$change_date <- as.Date(df$change_date)
df1<-group_by(df,Document) %>%
      summarise(latest=max(change_date))
df1$uid<-paste(df1$Document,df1$latest,sep="_")
df$uid<-paste(df$Document,df$change_date,sep="_")
df2<-merge(df1,df,"uid",x.all=TRUE)
df2<-df2[,c(2,6)]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `which.max` on 'change_date' to get the index of the maximum date and subset the 'status' based on that after grouping by 'Document'

```
df %>%
   group_by(Document) %>% 
   summarise(status = status[which.max(change_date)])
#     Document status
#      (dbl) (fctr)
#1        1      C
#2        2      D
```

---

Or after grouping by Document, we `arrange` the 'change_date' descendingly, get the first row of each group, `select` only the relevant columns after `ungroup`ing.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Document) %>% 
  arrange(desc(change_date)) %>% 
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-change_date)
#     Document status
#      (dbl) (fctr)
#1        1      C
#2        2      D
```

---

Using `data.table`, the syntax would be

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, .(status = status[which.max(change_date)]), by = Document]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
 df[with(df, ave(change_date, Document,
              FUN= max)==change_date), c(1,3)]
#    Document status
#4        1      C
#7        2      D
```

---

Or using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select Document, status
        from df 
        where change_date in (select max(change_date) from df
        group by "Document")')
#  Document status
#1        1      C
#2        2      D
```

NOTE: In the OP's post 'change_date' is `factor` class.  It should be converted to `Date` class before attempting the above solutions.

#### data

```
df$change_date <- as.Date(df$change_date)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit more used to dplyr, good to know data.table as an alternative!

Comment: @woshishui  In that case, didn't I also provided the compact `dplyr` code?

Comment: I'm relatively new to stackoverflow, and I can only accept one of the answers even though they're both correct! Anyway to get around this?

Comment: The above solutions give the same answer if there is a single maximum change_date row in each Document.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  I also provided one solution with `==`

Answer (score 3):

You can directly call `max(change_date)` in `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Document) %>% 
  filter(change_date == max(change_date)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) % in case you have duplicate records falling on the last date
```

Comment: thanks. never thought about the filter function.. it makes a lot of sense for this case.